# Why can't I "Configure Azure AD Authentication"

Tags: azure, active-directory, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I've got an ASP.NET Web project open in Visual Studio 2015. I right click, and select "Configure Azure AD Authentication". I get the following error:

> The Connected Services component 'Azure AD Authentication' failed:
>   (HRESULT:0x80131509) Could not resolve mscorlib for target framework
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5'.  This can happen if the target framework
>   is not installed or if the framework moniker is incorrectly formatted.

I'm running Windows 10, so I tried changing the project's target framework to 4.6, but I got a similar error. I also went to Windows Features and ensured that I had all of the .NET checkboxes installed.

Comment: Vivek, to help aid in the investigation can you try something?
On your machine, open 2 instances of Visual Studio.  In the first instance, open your ASP.NET Web project as normal.  In the second instance, Debug -> Attach to Process, and pick the devenv.exe process - which will be the first instance of Visual Studio.  Under Debug-> Windows -> Exception Settings, turn on to break on all 'Common Language Runtime Exceptions'.
Now back in the first instance, right click > "Configure Azure AD Authentication" again.  See if there are other exceptions happening besides "Could not resolve mscorlib..."

Comment: I didn't see any exceptions at all when I attached and repro'ed. The debug output didn't have anything alarming either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vivek,

-- Check your Nuget packages and make sure they are up to date --

I was experiencing the same issue.  This was with a project I had just created on another workstation and had parked it on a Git repository the night before.  After cloning and opening on my second workstation I right-clicked the project and chose the "Configure Azure AD Authentication" option just like you.  I got the same error.  I then went to my Nuget Package Manager and checked to see whether my packages were up to date.  Immediately I received an error from Nuget stating a package was missing, I clicked the 'Restore' button to restore it. Once it completed I discovered that there were several projects that required an update.  After updating the Nuget packages that were needing an update I went back to right-click the project and "Configure Azure AD Authentication".  No errors and I was able to proceed.  I hope that works for you.